# Get all elements by class name using DOMDocument

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

This question seems to have been answered numerous times but i still cant seem to put the pieces together.

I would like to get node value of every class by name. for example

```
<td class="thename"><strong>32</strong></td>
<td class="thename"><strong>12</strong></td>
```

i would like to grab the 32 and the 12. I assume this requires for sort of for loop but not sure exactly how to go about implementing it. Here's what i have so far

```
$domain = "http://domain.com";
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTMLFile($domain);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="thename"]')->item(0);
$stuff = $div ->textContent;

echo($stuff);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for?

```
    $result = array();

    $doc = <<< HTML
    <html>
        <body>
            <div>1
                <span>2</span>
            </div>
            <div>3</div>
            <div>4
                <span class="class1"><strong>5</strong></span>
                <span class="class1"><strong>6</strong></span>
                <span>7</span>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
HTML;
    $classname = "class1";
    $domdocument = new DOMDocument();
    $domdocument->loadHTML($doc);
    $a = new DOMXPath($domdocument);
    $spans = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $classname ')]");

    for ($i = $spans->length - 1; $i > -1; $i--) {
        $result[] = $spans->item($i)->firstChild->nodeValue;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
    exit();
```

Comment: that seems to do the trick. can you break down the xpath query. This is all new to me. thanks

Comment: I use [XPath 1.0](http://cweiske.de/tagebuch/XPath%3A%20Select%20element%20by%20class.htm), it makes no difference. You can use your variance `$query = '//*[@class="' . $className . '"]';`

Comment: $img_tags = $tags->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' thumbBlock ')]/div/div/a/img"); this gives me 500 internal server error

Answer (score 5):

i simply did this in php

```
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
           $classname = "product-name";

           @$dom->loadHTMLFile("http://shophive.com/".$query);
           $nodes = array();
           $nodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("div");
           foreach ($nodes as $element)
           {
               $classy = $element->getAttribute("class");
               if (strpos($classy, "product") !== false)
               {
                       echo $classy;
                       echo '<br>';
               }

           }
```

Comment: What if your product class is the first class in the string?

Comment: You check the string position for "product", whether it's larger than 0. But, if it's in first position, wouldn't your check fail (in strpos($classy, "product")>0)?

Comment: can you provide a test case ?

Comment: The point that @MastaBaba is trying to make is that strpos starts at position 0 (zero), not 1.  You are testing for > 0.  If "product" starts at the first spot in your string, your if test fails.  You should use: if (strpos($classy, "product") !== false) { echo ... }