# Getting Notice: Undefined offset error: 1 when using file_get_contents and explode

Tags: php

I am trying to figure out some things about getting data from an external page using the PHP *file_get_contents* function.

This is the PHP code I am trying to get to work:

```
$url = 'http://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/list/category/3/jet-aircraft/manufacturer/cessna/model/citation-mustang';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$first_step = explode('<div class="listing">',$content);
$second_step = explode("</div>",$first_step[1]);
echo $second_step[0];
```

It's a simple code to get the content of the divs with class 'listing' to echo on a page. For one reason or another, I keep getting the

> notice Undefined offset error: 1

and can't figure out a way to fix this. When I turn off error reporting, it just returns an empty page. I already read it has something to do with empty arrays or something, but not sure how to fix this.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is the output of `var_dump($content);` i am not able to test it at my end. got this `The requested URL /UserSettings/ScreenSize was not found on this server`

Comment: This echoes the content of the URL, so `<!DOCTYPE html><head> ... (length=208340)` So it does get the correct content from the website, I think the problem is in the code after that

Comment: The div with class "listing" doesn't exists on html returned by `file_get_contents($url)`, so the index 1 of `$first_step[1]` isn't set. That's why you get this error

Comment: @micster oh yes, it could be that. I just noticed I formulated that badly. What I need is the Divs that contain the word 'listing' in their class..

Comment: can you  post the output of `echo "<pre/>";print_r($first_step);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get element by class name using DOMDocument :

```
$url = 'http://www.controller.com/listings/aircraft/for-sale/list/category/3/jet-aircraft/manufacturer/cessna/model/citation-mustang';
$content = file_get_contents($url);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
if (!$doc->loadHTML($content)) {
    die ('error');
}
$a = new DOMXPath($doc);
$class = 'listing';
$divs = $a->query("//*[contains(concat(' ', normalize-space(@class), ' '), ' $class ')]");

// $divs contains every divs with "listing" in his class
// you can get content like that :

foreach ($divs as $div) {
    echo $div->nodeValue;
    // or
    echo $div->textContent;
}
```

More info with this question from stackoverflow : [Get all elements by class name using DOMDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184641/get-all-elements-by-class-name-using-domdocument)